# Replacing XML innerText with XMLElement or XElement

Tags: c#, xml

//I would like to get some advice on how to replace the node value of a element in XML using XMLElement or XElement. Right now I'm trying it with XMLElement but the compiler gives me only errors or the XML replace the whole document insted of selected node. I have a XML/XSD sample that I need to fill with data and create like 500 XML a day but I cant insert the data into the right elements.
I expect that I can replace / insert data into the element value. Like I want to change the City text value. I have a table with content and based on the filled data I need to add it into specific XML elements and save.
As for now every sample code I found and some I covered up did give compile errors / null reference object( at assigning InnerText) or deleted all the elements and added just one line with my text value.

Te code below gives me ''Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
' at .InnerText. Actually the declatarion of SelectSingleNode("ID") return me also a null.

```
-<Receiver>
  -<ID>
    <RNumber>9999999999</RNumber>
    <Name>ABC AGD sp. z o. o.</Name>
  </ID>
  -<Address>
    -<AddressSpec>
      <Country>PL</Country>
      <Street>Kwiatowa</Street>
      <HouseNum>1</HouseNum>
      <City>Warszawa</City>
   </AddressSpec>
 </Address>
   <Email>test@test.pl</Email>
   <Phone>667444555</Phone>
   </ID>
-</Receiver>


using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class ReplaceXMLData
{
public static void Main(Args _args)
{
    
    System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

    doc.Load(//path/sample.xml);

    System.Xml.XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
    
    System.Xml.XmlElement Street = doc.SelectSingleNode("Street");
   
    Street.innertext = "random";

    doc.AppendChild(root);
    doc.Save(path);
    info("Details  added Successfully");
 }}
```

Comment: I would generally suggest using LINQ to XML (XElement) as it's a much more modern API. But we don't know details about what you're trying to do, what you've tried, or what happened. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have added my sample code.

Comment: But you haven't told us what happens vs what you expected to happen. It would help if you'd show us what the file looks like beforehand too. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for a guide to asking a good question.

Comment: (As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to start following normal .NET naming conventions - and when you post a [mcve], please make it genuinely complete - we should be able to copy/paste/compile/run. Using a local file instead of `WinAPIServer` would help on that front too.)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to .NET, I expect that I can replace / insert data into the element value. Like I want to change the City text value. I have a table with content and based on the filled data I need to add it into specific XML elements and save. I'm not sure if I should create New XML from scratch every time or like I try now to use a base file and insert / replace the values in it.

Comment: Please *edit the question* with that information - but even with that, you still haven't told us in detail what happens with the code you've shown. (It should be fine to load the existing document and replace elements, but I would strongly recommend doing it with LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument.)

Comment: As for now every sample code I found and some I covered up did give compile errors / null reference object( at assigning InnerText) or deleted all the elements and added just one line with my text value. As you said I will try to do it with LinQ now and hope I can make a right call to the element value.

Comment: "As for now every sample code I found and some I covered up did give compile errors / null reference object" - but you haven't given us anything more precise than that. A good question should say *exactly* what happens with the code provided. Please read the link I provided earlier on, carefully.

Comment: Te code below gives me ''Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
' at .InnerText. Actually the declatarion of SelectSingleNode("ID") return me also a null.

Comment: There are three places where you use `.InnerText`, although two of them have incorrect casing, which means this presumably *isn't* the actual code you're running. Please, please focus on providing a [mcve]. It's *much* harder to help you without that.

Comment: Okay I updated the code. Now there is only one SelectSingleNode and InnerText. Select SingleNode returns me a null value and innerText gives me a nullreference. Im almost 100% sure its' because I don't know how to call the right element.

Comment: It's *still* not a [mcve] though. I can't copy, paste, compile and run. What is the `Args` type? What is `DocumentHistoryParameters`? Where's the class declaration and the `using` directives? (In .NET 6.0 it could be standalone, but then why have a `Main` method at all?) It's still definitely *not* the code you're running, as you declare a variable called `fileexists` and then assign to `fileExists`. This will be my last comment - I'm afraid I can't just spend time asking for improvements.

Comment: True I did add only the Main method of my class that has nothing else in it. To run it on my enviroment in AX365 I need to declare my MAIN method as it is in my sample. The code u mentioned really was not needed as I had there declared the path and checked if the file exist. BUT the ONLY thing I need is if "System.Xml.XmlElement Street = doc.SelectSingleNode("Street");" is declared correct or if not then how can I declare it so I can add/ change TEXT of this element.

Comment: Right - that's a much clearer example. And it's not correct because your XPath expression is looking for the `Street` element as a direct child of the expression you're calling it on.

Comment: Note that your `Main` method *still* has a parameter with type `Args`, which means it won't compile as far as I'm aware. What `Args` type do you expect this to be? Main methods normally have a `string[] args` parameter (or no parameter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution using Xml Linq (XDocument).  You need to use Decendants with FirstOrDefault

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication15
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement id = doc.Descendants("ID").FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```